# Hadoop Streaming with RVM does not find Gem

Tags: ruby, hadoop, rubygems, rvm, hadoop-streaming

Original Question (long version below). Short version: Running hadoop streaming with a ruby script as mapper and rvm installed on all cluster nodes does not work. Because ruby is not known (and rvm not being loaded correctly) by the hadoop launched shell. Why?

---

I wanted to use `wukong` as a gem to create map/reduce jobs for hadoop. The problem is the `wukong` gem can not be loaded by hadoop (ie it is not found). Hadoop jobs show me the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- wukong (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /tmp/mapr-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/admin/jobcache/job_201207061102_0068/attempt_201207061102_0068_m_000000_0/work/./test.rb:6:in `<main>'
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:572)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1109)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
```

However, doing `cat somefile | ./test.rb --map` works on all cluster machines as expected. Also I included some debug printing in my test file which I can retrieve von the hadoop logs. When running

```
$stderr.puts `gem list`
```

it yields all the gems including `wukong`, also

```
$stderr.puts $LOAD_PATH.inspect
```

yields the examt same paths as it does when printing the `$LOAD_PATH` running a local (not launched by hadoop) ruby script.

**Why does the hadoop launched ruby script not find the gem** which is clearly installed and working correctly?

---

hadoop is launched as:

```
hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-streaming.jar \
-libjars /opt/hypertable/current/lib/java/hypertable-0.9.5.6.jar,/opt/hypertable/current/lib/java/libthrift-0.8.0.jar \
-Dmapred.child.env="PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm" \
-mapper '/home/admin/wukong/test.rb --map' \
-file /home/admin/wukong/test.rb \
-reducer /bin/cat \
-input /test/test.rb \
-output /test/something2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to get it working by restarting all machines in the cluster. I assume `rvm` was not sourced correctly. Stange though that a reboot was needed.

Answer (score 0):

are you using ruby?

make sure that you run:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

and `echo $GEM_PATH` should return something like:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
```

if it does not it means the use command did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://zachmoshe.com/2015/02/23/use-ruby-gems-with-hadoop-streaming.html

It shows how to run ruby mappers with gems using Hadoop Streaming.

I know it's 3 years after you asked but maybe it'll help someone else..